# Someone recommended me a modern, not sure if kosher, book. Now I can't find it. What is the book called and is it kosher?

Tags: product-recommendation, women

Sorry if this is off topic but I am trying to find out about this book and needed a highly literate forum to ask. I didn't write down the title but off memory I thought it was called Kedushot u Kedushot, and that it was about Jewish women's spiritual experience, and it won some awards. But I can't find any book called that. Does anyone know what book this might be, and if it's worth reading? I think it was published in the last few years if that helps to identify it, and I got the recommendation after mentioning I read a book by Elliott Wolfson, so maybe it is the same genre of text.

If that name is wrong, what I am pretty sure I remember correctly is that it was too identical or almost identical words, probably 3 syllables each, with the word "u" in the middle of them.

Comment: https://www.worldcat.org/title/kedeshot-u-kedoshot-imahot-ha-mashiah-ba-mitos-ha-yehudi/oclc/892821263 this perhaps? If it's this, I strongly suspect it's not ""kosher"". It looks like an academic book, which means that very likely, anything goes. The title itself, Kedeshot u Kedushot includes the word kedeshot, which, though similar to kedusha, is actually the opposite. It means harlots.

Comment: The book is about traditions of the mother of the messiah in Judaism. There are some traditional Jewish sources that attest to such a character, including in the Talmud, but my guess is that this author would consider on the same level of legitimacy the Christian belief in Mary, mother of Jesus.

Comment: @Harel13 Thank you very much for identifying it, and for the warning. Would you say the same is true for reading academic publications on Kabbalah, like Divine and Demonic by Nathaniel Berman, and texts by Elliot Wolfson and Gershom Scholem? I have read them before and they do focus on sexual issues and discussions of that nature, but I thought this was necessary for educational reasons because these subjects do come up in Torah and Kabbalah. 

I read them because while I prefer Rabbinic literature, I wanted modern psychological, philosophical, historical, and deconstructive analysis.

Comment: @Harel13 And I was not aware of any modern Rabbinic texts that offer the same academic scholarship in those areas, but from a kosher Rabbi author instead of an academic. I thought I could learn from both separately and discard the bad from the academic teachings, since I did not know any authors who contained both positives in one Rabbi without any of the bad from the academic side. I would love recommendations if anyone knows.

Comment: If you're looking for psychology, literary history, textual evolution and criticism, you'll get all of that and more from such books. But you won't find real mysticism. As one of my rabbis once said: "[Academic] Scholars of Kabbalah are like accountants: they know where all of the money is but can't do anything with it."

Comment: This is true with a lot of Jewish fields studied from an academic perspective. It comes with removing the soul of the branch of study and then breaking everything apart. If that works for you, go for it. I think there's a lot to be gained from such analyses. But I recommend treading with care. These forms of research are *not* "Torah from heaven".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141474/discussion-between-shipbuilding-and-harel13).